# Unable to Change SVG Fill Color Using CSS Property

Tags: html, css, svg

I am endeavoring to alter the color of a specified SVG image. However, despite attempting various methods, it does not appear to be functioning as expected.

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img class="close-icon" src="icons/close-icon.svg" alt="close icon" />
  </body>
</html>
```

The SVG:

```
<svg 
    width="64" 
    height="64" 
    viewBox="0 0 16 16" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path
        fill = "currentColor"
        d="M11.293 3.293a1 1 0 1 1 1.414 1.414L9.414 8l3.293 3.293a1 1 0 0 1-1.414 1.414L8 9.414l-3.293 3.293a1 1 0 0 1-1.414-1.414L6.586 8 3.293 4.707a1 1 0 0 1 1.414-1.414L8 6.586z"
    />
</svg>
```

The CSS:

```
.close-icon {
  color: blue;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

The desired functionality is only achievable when directly embedding the SVG. Is there an alternative method to modify the property without relying on internal implementation?

Comment: No, there isn't a way to influence this from the page using an `img` tag, you _need_ to have the SVG data on the page. You could use symbols for repeated use, but that's the only way.

Comment: Maybe you could work with a `<div>` that has a background color and is clipped by an svg. You could then update the background color. Works only with one color tho. Edit: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path